# Creating a UDF for Count Ifs Visible and Multiple Criterias

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I am working on a data set that has multiple filter bars that can be selected and help search the data and provide how many meet its requirements among other things. E.g. by choosing a manager and partner name it looks through those lines in the data table. 
I have made it so it posts out a string of the text formula into boxes which are then concatenated and using a UDF Eval, enforced (it's needed to be broken down a lot due to lots of If and Else statements.

The thing is, as jobs are completed they are not deleted instead they are hidden.

How do I allow this data table to do a Count Ifs search with only looking at visible? Presumably its a UDF?

The ranges are from 6:1000

Below is the breakdown of the code I have. I need find a function to  make this code work only on visible.

I have made it so it posts out a string of the text formula into boxes which are then concatenated and using a UDF Eval, enforced (it's needed to be broken down a lot due to lots of If and Else statements.

The thing is, as jobs are completed they are not deleted instead they are hidden.

How do I allow this data table to do a Count Ifs search with only looking at visible? Presumably its a UDF?

The ranges are from 6:1000

Below is the breakdown of the code I have. I need find a function to  make this code work only on visible.

```
Sub SetCriteria()

If Sheet8.Range("E6").Value = 1 Then
'The 1 is displayed if there is a value placed in the filter part of the dashboard. If not this value remains 0.

 Sheet8.Range("F6") = "Tank!G6:G1000,Dashboard!C6,"
 'If there is a value in the filter, then the writing for the CountIf formaul is displayed, linking to the criteria.

Else: Sheet8.Range("F6") = "Tank!G6:G1000,""*"","
'If there isn't anything placed in the critieria then a wild card is selected to ensure all option for that catergory are chosen.
End If

If Sheet8.Range("E7").Value = 1 Then
'Same as above, though this time for Task Manager.
    Sheet8.Range("F7") = "Tank!I6:I1000,Dashboard!C7,"
Else: Sheet8.Range("F7") = "Tank!I6:I1000,""*"","
'The two different printed formulas, depending on criteria inclusion
End If


If Sheet8.Range("E8").Value = 1 Then
'Procedure for TAS Consultant
    Sheet8.Range("F8") = "Tank!J6:J1000,Dashboard!C8,"
Else: Sheet8.Range("F8") = "Tank!J6:J1000,""*"","
End If

If Sheet8.Range("E9").Value = 1 Then
'Procedure for Pillar
    Sheet8.Range("F9") = "Tank!H6:H1000,Dashboard!C9)"
Else: Sheet8.Range("F9") = "Tank!H6:H1000,""*"")"
End If

End Sub
```

EDIT: Here is my Evaluate Function

```
Function Eval(Ref As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Eval = Evaluate(Ref)
End Function
```

Comment: You could use a Subtotal, in combination with Offset and Sumproduct to count conditional on visible rows. No need for VBA, just plain excel-formulas

Comment: I don't understand how that would be done though as I have to use concatenate and my UDF eval to piece together the formula since it changes depending on search criteria?

Also ideally it would be in VBA as there are lots of people using this workbook who don't understand a lot of excel and so they may end up removing the formula etc.

Comment: Could you add your eval UDF also?

Answer (score 0):

Below array-formula to put in a cell, (Codename Sheet8 is Sheetname Sheet8 I assume)
close it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Tank!G6:G1000,ROW(Tank!G6:G1000)-MIN(ROW(Tank!G6:G1000)),,1))*(IF(Sheet8!E6=1,Tank!G6:G1000=Dashboard!C6,1))*(IF(Sheet8!E9=1,Tank!H6:H1000=Dashboard!C9,1))*(IF(Sheet8!E7=1,Tank!I6:I1000=Dashboard!C7,1))*(IF(Sheet8!E8=1,Tank!J6:J1000=Dashboard!C8)))
```

This formula is instead of your Sub setcriteria and your Eval function,
You could also break it down as you did before and put it in your eval function.
(Not visible rows must be filtered)

But when you go the VBA-route, have a look at looping your range, only visible rows, check for the criteria and count if met.